# datepicker is not working my design page why

Tags: jquery

Hi I have designed a page in that page I wrote a code for date picker why its not working please tell me the reason

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqLudp1e/1/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
        <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">
            <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="studentDOB" /> <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#studentDOB').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        minDate: 0
    }).on('changeDate',function (e) {
          $('#studentEnrollmentForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'studentDOB');
       })
});
```

Comment: You have placed the id on your div
`<div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">`

Comment: 1) your selector needs to target your `input` rather than your `div`. 2) your jsFiddle didn't import jQueryUi as an external resource.

Comment: Please accept the answer to close the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed script:
https://jsfiddle.net/aquadk/gqLudp1e/3/

```
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
    <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="studentDOB" /> <span
            class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the same code what i posted above is working fine with other jquery version

Comment: in my code if i going to select date am getting hand mark here not why

Comment: @Rene lykke  you have added datepicker.js is really needed, I don't think so

Comment: the datepicker is not standard in jquery, You need to include this lib.

Answer (score 1):

your selector is targeting your `div` rather than your `input` change it back to `input`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 ">
        <div class="input-group input-append date">
            <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="studentDOB" id="studentDOB" /> <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also your jsFiddle didn't import jQueryUi as an external resource